# why is data-id returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I do not understand why the below code isnt working for me. Console returning 'undefined' for data-id

```
href='#detailsModal' class='btn btn-info btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-id='xyz'>BUTTON NAME
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $('#detailsModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log($(e.relatedTarget).data('id'));
 });
```

I expect out console output to be 'xyz'

Comment: You dont have `id` attributes on/inside your modal

Comment: Why are you using `relatedTarget`? You need to add more detail to your question about how you expect your code to work

Comment: Does `console.log( e.relatedTarget.dataset.id)` work? If It does the issue is more likely to be with jQuery than bootstap.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `data-target` attribute for modal trigger. Use `data-target="#detailsModal"` instead of `href="#detailsModal"`.